# setcookie and ask cookie value for voting system

Tags: php, cookies, vote

I want to set a cookies to get the users only vote once in 4 categories (sad, enraging, funny, cool).
I'm a beginner so I know my code is very inconvenient but it is my first try and so it doesen't matter to me if I have a few lines more or less.
For some reason the browser won't load the vote.php files (that are called when the user clicks one voting option). I just can't find the error...maybe someone sees it immediatly?
[Before I inserted the cookie thing the code files loaded perfectly, so the calling isn't the matter.]

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$newsid = $_POST['id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['votecookie']) && $_COOKIE['votecookie'] !== 'sad') {
        if($_COOKIE['votecookie'] == 'cool') {  
            $query = mysql_query('UPDATE `index` SET cool=cool-1 WHERE id = {$newsid}');
        }
        if($_COOKIE['votecookie'] == 'funny') { 
            $query = mysql_query('UPDATE `index` SET funny=funny-1 WHERE id = {$newsid}');
        }
        if($_COOKIE['votecookie'] == 'sad') {   
            $query = mysql_query('UPDATE `index` SET enraging=enraging-1 WHERE id = {$newsid}');
        }
        setcookie('votecookie', 'sad');
        $query = mysql_query('UPDATE `index` SET sad=sad+1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'');
        $hosts = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extras = 'news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=1';
        header('Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras');
        exit;
    }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['votecookie']) {
            setcookie('votecookie', 'sad');
            $query = mysql_query('UPDATE `index` SET sad=sad+1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'');
            $hosts = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
            $extras = 'news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=1';
            header('Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras');
            exit;
        }

        if(isset($_COOKIE['votecookie']) && $_COOKIE['votecookie'] == 'sad') {
            $hosts= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
            $extras = 'news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=0';
            header('Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras');
            exit;
        }
        }
    else {
        $hosts= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extras = 'news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=0';
        header('Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras');
        exit;
        ?>
```

Comment: You should use sessions instead. Users can modify and delete cookies

Comment: Why do you have `if($_COOKIE['votecookie'] == 'sad')` when you're inside a block that only runs when `votecookie` is _not_ `sad`?

Comment: With respect to header('Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras'); - because these are single quotes the literal value is being used - it is trying to redirect to http://$hosts$uris/$extras.  Use double quotes to parse variables in strings. https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Are you expecting `setcookie('votecookie', 'sad')` in the first `if` block to update `$_COOKIE['votecookie']` that's tested in the next `if`? `$_COOKIE` is only set when you refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
@Barmar: the thing with sad was indeed a mistake and i corrected it. And to your second question: no I don't expect it

Comment: @user2182349 I corrected the quotes thing.
Although I edited these mistakes it will not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested in the answer: This is how I did it now (I had a few more mistakes in my code and an error in reasoning).

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$newsid = $_POST['id'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$newsid]) && $_COOKIE[$newsid] != 'sad') {
        if($_COOKIE[$newsid] == 'cool') {   
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `index` SET cool=cool-1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'");
        }
        if($_COOKIE[$newsid] == 'funny') {  
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `index` SET funny=funny-1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'");
        }
        if($_COOKIE[$newsid] == 'enraging') {   
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `index` SET enraging=enraging-1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'");
        }
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `index` SET sad=sad+1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'");
    setcookie($newsid, "sad", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    $hosts = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extras = "news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=1";
    header("Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras");
        exit;
    }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$newsid])) {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `index` SET sad=sad+1 WHERE id = '{$newsid}'");
        setcookie($newsid, "sad", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
        $hosts = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extras = "news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=1";
        header("Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras");
            exit;
    }   
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$newsid]) && $_COOKIE[$newsid] == 'sad') {
        $hosts= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extras = "news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=0";
        header("Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras");
            exit;
    }
}
else {
    $hosts= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uris = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extras = "news.php?id={$newsid}&sad=0";
    header("Location: http://$hosts$uris/$extras");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain specifically what you changed? It's hard to see the differences.